# AT commands in screen/minicom

Tags: screen, minicom

I can connect to serial port in /dev/ttyUSB0 using screen or minicom. When I type the AT commands, the letters I type do not appear, just the output message. Example: If a type "AT" and press enter, the "AT" doest not appear, but the "OK" output message appear normally. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Ctrl+A, then E.

This way minicom will echo the typed symbols on screen.

You can enable echo in device itself, if it supports it by

```
ATE
```

command.

Comment: You're an old fart for just knowing this!  **;-)** +1

Comment: @Fabby your comment is gold

Comment: @Grizzly Another greybeard!  **;-)**